# AngualrJS directive called multiple times using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, html5-video, html5-audio

I have an HTML audio player called as part of a directive in AngularJS. Upon page refresh the player works perfectly - I can set the source and play audio - console logs this : 
[image]
However, if I navigate to another state in my app and THEN load/play the audio, 2 instances of the audio begin to play. If I visit 4 states before playing, 4 instances of the audio will play! Console logs this: 
[image]

**Why is the audio player being initiated over and over? How can I keep it active as I move between states? I don't want to destroy it and reinitialize it each time I change state, that would interrupt the audio playback.**

Here is the relevant code. Essentially the view footer.html contains the directive and player, and is being included by each state.

index.html :

```
  ...
  <div style="clear:both"></div>

  <div ui-view="footer"></div>
</body>
```

app.js :

```
.state('audiolist', {
      url: '/audiolist/',
      views: {
        sideNav: {
          templateUrl: 'views/sideNav.html',
          controller: 'sideNavController'
        },
        header: {
          templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
          controller: 'headerController'
        },
        content: {
          templateUrl: 'views/list.main.html',
          controller: 'listController as content'
        },
        footer: {
          templateUrl: 'views/footer.html',
          controller: 'apController as ap'
        }
      })
    ...
    .state('saveditems', {
      url: '/saveditems/',
      views: {
        sideNav: {
          templateUrl: 'views/sideNav.html',
          controller: 'sideNavController'
        },
        header: {
          templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
          controller: 'headerController'
        },
        content: {
          templateUrl: 'views/saveditems.main.html',
          controller: 'savedItemsController as content'
        },
        footer: {
          templateUrl: 'views/footer.html',
          controller: 'apController as ap'
        }
      }
...
```

footer.html

```
    <div class="audioplayer">
      <!-- Audio Player -->
      <hls-player id="player" playlist="{{ap.tracks}}"></hls-player>
...
```

directives/hlsPlayer.js

```
module.directive('hlsPlayer', function ($window, $templateRequest, $compile, $http, $rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $templateRequest("views/playerTemplate.html").then(function (html) {
        // player functions 
        ... 
        // play function 
           ...
           console.log("manifest loaded, found " + data.qualities + " quality level");
           console.log("audio loaded and playing");
    ...
```

playerTemplate.html

```
...
 <audio autobuffer preload="metadata" src="" id="radio" class="hidden" preload="none"></audio>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change the state, AngularJS initializes the controllers again. The directive `hlsPlayer` has the same scope as the controller. So `link` is called again.

You can use `$on "$destroy"` to finish directive's work gracefully to stop the player.

```
element.on('$destroy', function () {
     // stop/destroy here the player
});
```

---

As a side note, I suggest you to use the service to store player instance and avoid such things like initializing the player into directives

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The problem is if I destroy the player the audio will stop and no longer be persistent. The service idea is probably necessary

Answer (score 0):

My solution, which will not work in every case, was to move the HTML5 player  itself out of the directive template, and place it in the main index.html page. 
This works well for persistent audio in Angular, and I can still load, control and display a timeline as before by referencing that audio element. For example:

index.html:

```
<audio id="mediaPlayer" autobuffer preload="metadata" src="" id="radio" class="hidden" preload="none"></audio>
```

Directive :

```
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
 $templateRequest("views/playerTemplate.html").then(function (html) {
            var template = angular.element(html);

            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())($scope);

            var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('#mediaPlayer'));
            var audio = elem[0];

            $scope.play = function () {               
                    audio.play();
                }
```

playerTemplate.html (use $scope vars and functions from directive to operate player)

```
<a type="button" ng-click="played=!played; played ? play() :stop();"><i
                ng-class="played?'nav-btn-play fa fa-pause-circle-o':'nav-btn-play fa fa-play-circle-o'"></i></a>
```